# How do I deal with a disallowed_useragent error on a website I designed?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I've designed and launched a standalone website which uses Google login and the `gapi` library they provide. When I sent the link to some people over Facebook, they're are reporting they get a "disallowed_useragent" when they try and log in, I assume because the browser they're accessing it from is sending a bad user-agent.

I have no idea how to avoid this error. Google's blog says "Developers can acknowledge the deprecation and remove this notice from the consent page by including a URL parameter "suppress_webview_warning=true" in the request." but I don't see any way of doing that with the `gapi` library.

Ideally, I'd like some way to allow this, or at least a way to detect that it's happened and provide a user-friendly message to my users. Failing that, I'd like a way to know if it's going to happen and tell users so they don't waste their time. What can I do?

Comment: It works help to know what browser is generating that error. The "webview" blog is about users who are using embedded webview. Is that your situation?

Comment: I have a standalone website. I sent the link to some people in Facebook. They're getting that error when they click on the link, and are telling me my site is broken.

Comment: Are they opening the link within the FB app or in Chrome? Like I said, you need to know what browser they are using?

Comment: The point is, I don't know what browser they're using. They could be using anything. All I know is that I'm sending a link in chat, they're clicking it and getting an error.

How can I prevent that error from happening?

Comment: The fix that you are looking to implement from your question only deals with a specific scenario, ie webviews. Somehow you need to determine if that's what is going on. You're http server logs should tell you which browsers are being used. You might need to around your problem by giving your users instructions to copy paste the link into a supported browser instead of clicking the link from chat.

Comment: I have a website. That website is broken when people access it from some browsers. I would like to deal with the problem gracefully, before users encounter it, not plaster my website with ugly disclaimers like "NOT COMPATIBLE WITH IE 10" and I certainly don't know how to explain to my end users what an "embedded web view" is.

Google knows the user agents which trigger this problem. I'd like to know what they are, or if there's a call I can make to see if one is blacklisted, or if there's at least a way, after the fact, to know it occurred.